# Install windows 8 after Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, windows-8

It's the first time I install Ubuntu before windows and thats why I failed so much so I need your help.
I have 64bit Ubuntu 12.10 and I left some space to add Windows 8 later. The time for Windows came and I put the bootable USB stick to install it, but get stuck - choosing any partition, including ntfs one, return this message:

```
windows cannot be installed on this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style.
```

I've googled it for some info, but all I understand is that I have partition table that Windows does not like and support. One solution would be to backup entire data, install Windows and then restore my Ubuntu, but I think there should be easier way.
There is my partition table:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After receiving the same error as you above, I was able to install Windows 8 by rebooting the computer with my Windows 8 install disk already in the DVD drive and then from the motherboard's bios boot menu selecting the DVD drive that started with "UEFI". My boot menu had the DVD drive listed twice in the menu; the second time without the UEFI. It was only by selecting the option with the UEFI prefix that I was able to install Windows 8.